# Using ogr2ogr in Python to import data to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: python, ogr2ogr, gml

Currently I use the following command to batch import multiple GML files to PostGIS database:

```
set dirgml= C:\data\  

set app=ogr2ogr
set opt=-update -append -progress
set dst=-f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=username 
password=password active_schema=public"

for %%G IN ('dir/b %dirgml%\*) do %app% %opt% %dst% "%%G"
```

Can you do the same thing by using a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

yes use the subprocess library. Make a function like I did below and just insert your variables into the command in a for loop

```
import os
import subprocess

folder=r'path'
db_connection="host=localhost dbname=hmm user=postgres password=apassword"

def submittal(folder,db):
    cmd='ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES "{0}" PG:"{1}" -sql "select geom from my table" -t_srs EPSG:3424 -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -overwrite -nln exported_table'.format(folder,db)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    
submittal(folder,db_connection)
```

Comment: It is also possible to use https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslate without subprocess.

Comment: @user30184 cool..post an example ive never seen that used

Comment: Many usage examples in GDAL GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_ogr2ogr_lib.py.

Comment: @user30184 I looked at examples in GDAL GitHub, but struggle to understand how to apply these logic to my example, can you advise? thanks

Comment: @ziggy I've never used subprocess, so appriciate if you could suggest the script that can be apply to my example if possible? thanks

Comment: @ColtonM just loop through your data folder and insert each gml file into an on the fly ogr2ogr command

Comment: @ziggy thank you! I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Not using ogr2ogr, but you can read GML files using geopandas.

`gdf = geopandas.read_file('path to gml')`

And then upload to PostGIS using

`gdf.to_postgis()`

[geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis.html)

Comment: Thanks, there are a lot of gml files to upload (over 500 and covers half of UK, it's os mastermap topography data) - my concern is this method may not work due to sheer voume of data?